# add id and class attributes to ajaxDisplay appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, json

i have this code which works correctly and is giving me the **name** and **price** of a product. now i want to add a `class` and `id` attribute to each of the entries.

```
tab.innerHTML += "<p>"+data[h].name+"</p>";
tab.innerHTML += "<p>"+data[h].price+"</p>";
```

Comment: do you want to add it dynamically? if so is there any event for that.

Comment: the above cod is inside a loop which display all the products. so is it possible to have a new id for every time it loops? the data are loaded automatically when the site is loaded.

Comment: to what element you want to add Id and Name. is it <p> tag.

Comment: yes <p> but it could also be anything that works.

Comment: What do you want to use for the `id` and `class` attributes in your paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you have a custom id. The id is the key of the data followed by the name of the attribute.

```
tab.innerHTML += "<p id='"+h+"name' class='className'>"+data[h].name+"</p>";
tab.innerHTML += "<p id='"+h+"price' class='className'>"+data[h].price+"</p>";
```

Comment: it works for the id but when it tries to get the class name it's undifined

Comment: thanks i only wanted unique id so i removed the `"+ h +"` from the class and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

For class, use this

```
tab.className = "class-name";
```

For id, use this

```
tab.id = "id-name";
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it adds class name and id to the `tab` which in my case is `div`

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are using jquery

```
$("p").attr('id',dynamicValue);
$("p").attr('class','sampleclass');
```

you can use something like this inside loop if you are using Jquery.

Comment: No jQuery mentioned here